# Spring Data Rest web service iterating result cannot cast class to Object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I'm having a difficult time iterating through the result of my REST service and I need help to find out what the issue is. My entity is as follows:

```java
@Entity
@IdClass(EntityClass.class)
@XmlRootElement
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "EntityClass.getEntityById",
            query = " select id,null as list from table where....",
            resultClass = EntityClass.class, resultSetMapping = "ResultMap"
    )
})
@SqlResultSetMappings({
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "ResultMap",
            columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Integer.class)
                ,        
                 @ColumnResult(name = "list")
                ,}
    )})
public class EntityClass implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Integer ID_REQUISICION;
    private ArrayList SUPPLIERS_LIST;

    //getters,setters,etc...
}
```

I reckon the problem might be here as it works without a flaw if I use `@ConstructorResult`. However I don't want to have a constructor as in my real POJO entity I have 22 parameters and its not efficient.

We have the repository as well:

```java
@Repository
public interface Entityrepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<EntityClass, Long> {
   List<EntityClass> getEntityById(String param );    
}
```

And the controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/path/{param}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
List<EntityClass> getEntities(@PathVariable("param") String param) {
        Iterable<EntityClass> iter = entityRepository.getEntityById(param);
    List<EntityClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (EntityClass q : iter) {
        if (q.getACTIVE() == 0) {
            q.setList(new ArrayList());
        } else {
            q.setList(new ArrayList());
        }
        list.add(q);
    }
    return list;
}
```

If I were to return:

```java
Iterable<EntityClass> iter = entityRepository.getEntityById(param);
```

It would work if I initialize the list with this and return it it will work as well. The problem lays that I get the cannot cast `Object` to `EntityClass` when I try to iterate through it.

Any Ideas?

Comment: can you share the failing code?

Comment: In postman i get nosuchmethoderror by jackson (500) and in the browser i get the cannot cast class Object to package.EntityClass. Im unable to get further logs because of the way the project has been configured.:S Hope it helps